# Delete a post if there is no comment inside

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, graphql, apollo

I am trying to delete a post if there are no comments inside. This actually works but I don't get the return message if a post gets deleted. The server response is : **"errors": [{ "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Post.id.",..**

How can I do this without an error message or even what's a better way to delete a post that has no comments?

```
async deleteComment(_, { postId, commentId }, context) {
        const { username } = checkAuth(context);

        const post = await Post.findById(postId);
        if (post) {
            const commentIndex = post.comments.findIndex(
                (c) => c.id === commentId
            );

            if (post.comments[commentIndex].username === username) {
                post.comments.splice(commentIndex, 1); 
                await post.save();
                if (post.comments.length < 1) {
                    console.log("No comments available";
                    await post.delete();
                    return "Successfully deleted post"; // I want to get the message
                }
                return post;
            } else {
                throw new AuthenticationError("Action not allowed");
            }
        } else {
            throw new UserInputError("Post not found");
        }
    },
```

Comment: ` return "Successfully deleted post"; // I want to get the message` vs `return post;` ... 1st one doesn't return post (probably mutation result type) ... just `return post` (no error = success) or extend return type (with some message firld)